# Isometric Tile Picking Giving Negative Values

Tags: java, game-engine, isometric

I need to find the coordinates for isometric tiles when it's clicked. I've got it mostly figured out. The Y values are returning correctly, but apparently my X formula is incorrect and I'm receiving back negative values.

Exhibit A:

The gray tile is supposed to be 0, 0 but for some reason I'm getting -5...
[image]

Here's my code.

Here we make the map (Probably not be relevant to the question but here just to show how I'm doing things). ObjectID is just an enum storing the tile types.

```
ObjectID tile_map[][] = new ObjectID[][] {
                {ObjectID.Ground_Concrete, ObjectID.Ground_Grass, ObjectID.Ground_Grass, ObjectID.Ground_Grass},
                {ObjectID.Ground_Grass, ObjectID.Ground_Grass, ObjectID.Ground_Grass, ObjectID.Ground_Grass},
                {ObjectID.Ground_Grass, ObjectID.Ground_Grass, ObjectID.Ground_Grass, ObjectID.Ground_Grass},
                {ObjectID.Ground_Grass, ObjectID.Ground_Grass, ObjectID.Ground_Grass, ObjectID.Ground_Grass},
                {ObjectID.Ground_Grass, ObjectID.Ground_Grass, ObjectID.Ground_Grass, ObjectID.Ground_Grass},
        };
```

We load the map looping through the array above and adding them to a LinkedList (via handler.addObject()) storing their x and y values and tile type, as well as their widths and heights.

```
private void loadMap(ObjectID map[][]) {
    int x = offsetX, y = offsetY;
    //int tile_width = 128, tile_height = 128;
    for(int i = 0; i < map.length; i++) {
        for(int j = map[i].length-1; j >= 0; j--) {

            handler.addObejct(new objGround(x + (j * map[i][j].getWidth() / 2) + (i * map[i][j].getWidth() / 2), y + (i * map[i][j].getBottomGroundPlane() / 2) - (j * map[i][j].getBottomGroundPlane() / 2), map[i][j]));
        }
    }
}
```

Our MouseListener

```
        private class MouseListener extends MouseInputAdapter {
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                if(!dragging) {
                    getTileByXY(e.getX(), e.getY());
                }
            }

public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
            //System.out.println("mosue pressed");

            if(SwingUtilities.isRightMouseButton(e)) {
                if(e.getX() != mX || e.getY() != mY) {
                    dragging = true;
                    if(e.getX() < mX) {
                        offsetX -= (mX - e.getX());
                    } else {
                        offsetX += (e.getX() - mX);
                    }
                    if(e.getY() < mY) {
                        offsetY -= (mY - e.getY());
                    } else {
                        offsetY += (e.getY() - mY);
                    }

                    mX = e.getX();
                    mY = e.getY();

                    //System.out.println("ox: " + offsetX + " oy: " + offsetY);
                }
            }
        }
    ...
    }
```

And finally our Tile Getter where the main problem lies at htx:

```
private void getTileByXY(int x, int y) {
        int tileW = 127;
        int tileH = 63;

        x += (tileW * 2);
        y += (tileH * 2);

        int htx = (int)(((double)(offsetX - x) / (double)tileW) + ((double)(offsetY - y) / (double)tileH) - 0.5);
        int hty = (int)(((double)(offsetY - y) / (double)tileH) - ((double)(offsetX - x) / (double)tileW) + 0.5);

        System.out.println("htx: " + htx + " hty: " + hty);
    }
```

Comment: Is the offset the distance from the side of the view to the first tile? Have you tried subtracting the offset from the x value?

Comment: Yes, offset is the distance from the left (offsetX) and top (offsetY) of the window.

Comment: What values are you using for the offsets?

Comment: Then I would look at subtracting the offsetX from x, rather than the other way around. I think that's where your negative values are coming from.

Comment: Ah ok! That makes it start at 4 now. At least we're getting positive numbers... Now to figure out why its not starting at zero.

Comment: Is the vertical offset for the left-most cell, or the bottom-most cell?

Comment: They both draw from the Left-most.

Answer (score 0):

Experimenting with Photoshop and Excel and assuming that your origin is top left, your offsetX is the left side of the left-most cell and your offsetY is the bottom of the left-most cell:

```
int htx = (int)(((double)(x - offsetX) / (double)tileW) - ((double)(offsetY - y) / (double)tileH) + 0.5);
int hty = (int)(((double)(offsetY - y) / (double)tileH) + ((double)(x - offsetX) / (double)tileW) - 0.5);
```

Comment: That actually only breaks the Y coords which are working fine in the original code. Here is where I am currently (I know its going to post ugly):

int htx = (int)(((double)(x - offsetX) / (double)tileW) + ((double)(y - offsetY) / (double)tileH) - 0.5);

int hty = (int)(((double)(offsetY - y) / (double)tileH) - ((double)(offsetX - x) / (double)tileW) + 0.5);

Comment: This was based on testing in Excel (and it works in Excel) using your image for the coords. I need to know whether your origin (0,0) is in the top left. Also, what the actual values for offsetX and offsetY are.

Comment: The gray tile in the picture is (0, 0). offsetX and offsetY are arbitrary. They start at 0 until I drag the map around with the mouse. The tiles return the same values before and after offset is adjusted, meaning changing the offset doesnt directly affect the tile coordinates, only their literal on screen x/y values.

Comment: You are trying to map between view coordinates (which I assume start at 0,0 in the top left corner of the view) and tiles. The offset values are not arbitrary - they specify what the distance between the left of the view and the left of the 0,0 tile is, and the distance between the top of the view and the bottom of the 0,0 tile. I made this work in Excel by using pixel values from your image. I suggest that's where you start.

Comment: I finally got it working! I posted my findings in an answer. Thanks for your help along the way.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is I was adding tileW * 2 and tileH * 2 to x and y. That was from the example that I originally found. Commenting them out fixed it and now the tiles return the correct values!

```
//x += (tileW * 2);
//y += (tileH * 2);

int htx = (int)(((double)(x - offsetX) / (double)tileW) + ((double)(y - offsetY) / (double)tileH) - 0.5);
int hty = (int)(((double)(offsetY - y) / (double)tileH) - ((double)(offsetX - x) / (double)tileW) + 0.5);
```